# Uml Sequence Diagram: Drawing new operator in comparison with default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, uml, sequence-diagram, new-operator

Could someone tell me the how to draw the differences in a sequence diagram with the following C++ code example. I tried to be as clear as possible:)

### main

```
#include "classa.h"

int main()
{
    ClassA a;
    return 0;
}
```

### classa.h

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H
#include "classb.h"

class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA();
    ~ClassA();
private:
    ClassB *var1;
    ClassB var2;
};

#endif // CLASSA_H
```

### classb.h

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H

class ClassB
{
public:
    ClassB();
    void test();
};

#endif // CLASSB_H
```

### classa.cpp

```
#include "classa.h"

ClassA::ClassA()
{
    var1 = new ClassB;
    var1->test();
    var2.test();
}

ClassA::~ClassA()
{
    delete var1;
}
```

### classb.ccp

```
#include "classb.h"

ClassB::ClassB()
{
}

void ClassB::test()
{
    //Here some code
}
```

I Think the image below is used for the new operator (var1), but how is var2 drawn?

[image: UML Diagram]

Comment: Added diagram on your behalf from the link you mentioned. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

My c++ is a bit rusty but I think something like this: [image: sequence diagram]

`var2` gets allocated automatically when `a` is created - so is created before `var1`. As far as UML is concerned, it's still creation of a new class instance.  There may be ways to further stereotype the `<<create>>` operation to indicate creation on the stack vs. heap but can't say I've ever used them. Like I say though, my C++ is a bit rusty.

hth.